# How to customize Component of Ant Design?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I'm using Ant Design for my project, I built complete web app with ReactJS, now I need to customize components to match with designer, how can I do it? I read Ant Design's docs, but it's just change some default variable. Thanks!

I tried using webpack to customize some default value but it's still not work

[Codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-brattain-iwkuu?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme

Comment: Hi qnujoow, I tried tutorial of ant design, but it's still not work. I made a reproduce here, can you check it? https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-brattain-iwkuu?file=/src/index.js

Comment: If you see in dev tools, ant design has classes associated with its elements, you can target those in CSS.  For example, your button had these "<button type="button" class="ant-btn ant-btn-primary"></button>"

Comment: I have read some answer about this, they said that I can target them "in your less file" so how can I make that file? or just create and import into the component I need to customize?

Comment: its a simple CSS class in the end, you can use normal CSS stylesheet or other CSS libraries

Comment: You can override the styles by importing the same class used in the page by inspecting in dev tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a module can help me easy to customize Ant Design, thank guys!
Its [craco-antd](https://github.com/DocSpring/craco-antd)